# Multiple Images in an input box (Google Searchbar)

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to coding. I am working on recreating the Google home page for The Odin Project and I cannot seem to get the images to sit right in the  search bar.

Thus far all of my code and formatting has been done in HTML. I was struggling how to do CSS and push it via Git. anyway...

I got the magnifying glass to sit in the proper spot, but when I went to add the microphone image, it overlaps the magnifying glass. The code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
<!--FONTS-->
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&display=swap');


body{
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  max-width: 90%;

}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 350px;
}

button {
  width: 127px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;

}

input {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
}

.btn-toolbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;

}

.btn-toolbar button:hover {
  background-color: #88888888;
}

ul {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: #777;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
}

.column {
  float: left;
}

.footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;

}

.header{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;

}

h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fake-input{
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.fake-input input{
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fake-input img{
position: absolute;
top: 11px;
left: 10px;
}



</style>
  

    <div class="row">
      <header id="header" class="header">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">

          <li>
            <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">About</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Store</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">images</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">gmail</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">squares</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">circle</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <body>
    </div>
    <!-- Google Logo -->
    <div>
        <h1><img style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 60px;" class="center" id="google-image" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
        </h1>
      </div>
    <div>
      <!--Google search bar -->
      <!-- Search input text -->
      <div class="fake-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type URL" />
        <img id="msgnify" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/13/01/22/magnifying-glass-1976105_1280.png" width=15 />
      
        <img id="mic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Google_mic.svg/833px-Google_mic.svg.png" width=15>
      </div>
      
      
      <br>

      <!-- Search Buttons -->
      <div style="padding-top: 20px;" class="btn-toolbar">
        <button>Google Search</button>
        <button>I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
      </div>
 
    </div>
    <br>
  </body>
    <!-- footer contains link to the respective locations -->
    <div class="row">
      <footer id="footer" class="footer">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">

          <li>
            <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Advertising</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Business</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">How Search Works</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Privacy</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Terms</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
    </div>
  














</html>
```

I tried changing the class, giving it an id, setting the position to relative and margin right as auto, but i cannot seem to get it to move over to the right side of the search bar.

Additionally, the buttons below the search bar are stuck together. I had each button as its own, but the moment I added them to the same div they have become ajoined and when I try to separate them, the only way i can get them on them aligned is by styling them to the same row. Margin does not help split them apart, I even tried to get them in separate columns no dice. I am really frustrated as i made it pretty far in a day just using HTML. I would like to keep it HTML until I learn how to push CSS to GitHub via Git.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with either Git or GitHub (at least at this point): it's all HTML and CSS here. Why the [tag:git] and [tag:github] tags?

Comment: I guess i was trying to get a quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the `fake-input` to `position: relative` and the image to `position: absolute` which is already correct, but for the `img#mic` you need to set it's position `right` and not `left` to make it appear in the right side of the `fake-input`, so I add some style like this

```
.fake-input img#mic{
  position: absolute;
  left: unset;
  right: 10px;
}
```

And for the button, it's working if you add the `margin` for the `button` like in the updated snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
<!--FONTS-->
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&display=swap');


body{
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  max-width: 90%;

}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 350px;
}

button {
  width: 127px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
}

input {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
}

.btn-toolbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;

}

.btn-toolbar button:hover {
  background-color: #88888888;
}

ul {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: #777;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
}

.column {
  float: left;
}

.footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;

}

.header{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;

}

h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fake-input{
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.fake-input input{
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fake-input img{
position: absolute;
top: 11px;
left: 10px;
}

.fake-input img#mic{
position: absolute;
left: unset;
right: 10px;
}

</style>
  

    <div class="row">
      <header id="header" class="header">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">

          <li>
            <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">About</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Store</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">images</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">gmail</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">squares</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">circle</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <body>
    </div>
    <!-- Google Logo -->
    <div>
        <h1><img style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 60px;" class="center" id="google-image" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
        </h1>
      </div>
    <div>
      <!--Google search bar -->
      <!-- Search input text -->
      <div class="fake-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type URL" />
        <img id="msgnify" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/13/01/22/magnifying-glass-1976105_1280.png" width=15 />
      
        <img id="mic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Google_mic.svg/833px-Google_mic.svg.png" width=15>
      </div>
      
      
      <br>

      <!-- Search Buttons -->
      <div style="padding-top: 20px;" class="btn-toolbar">
        <button>Google Search</button>
        <button>I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
      </div>
 
    </div>
    <br>
  </body>
    <!-- footer contains link to the respective locations -->
    <div class="row">
      <footer id="footer" class="footer">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">

          <li>
            <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Advertising</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Business</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">How Search Works</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Privacy</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Terms</a>
          <a class="column" href="https://www.google.com">Settings</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
    </div>
  














</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. I guess i need to take a harder look at how i have things nestled. I had also never seen the margin "unset" before. but after a quick search, i now know why.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should give position :relative to class (fake-input);
   then give position :absolute to (search.png or mic.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i would like to know more about your response. It seems as though I had the first part correct, but I do not understand the rest of your comment.